# Domain leads to Apache default page instead of the desired page

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

I have set up a server, and created additional virtual hosts with their document roots being /var/www/example.com But whenever I got to example.com it leads to the default "its working" Apache page.

If I go to example.com/example.com/index.html however it displays the code that I would have liked to display by default.

Thank you for your help.

---- In Response To Carlos ----

Here is the code you asked for

```
        > apache2ctl -S  
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message  
VirtualHost configuration:  
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost  
         default server example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)  
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)  
         port 80 namevhost 2.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/2.example.com.conf:1)  
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:1)  
                 alias www.example.com  
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"  
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"  
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"  
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl   
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults  
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults  
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"  
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS  
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG  
User: name="www-data" id=33  
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Comment: Do you enable the vhosts? a2ensite * can help you.

Comment: Yes the vhosts are enabled

Comment: Can you share your apache configuration?

Comment: please show how to apache are parsing your vhost.

Comment: please show how to apache are parsing your vhost.  

apache2ctl -S (if you use ubuntu or any debian like)

Comment: I added the what I got after entering apache2ctl

Comment: People also asked for your configuration. Unless you include that, it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

your are using example.com for the default vhost and the first vhost.  That is the reason why you are displaying the default site, and not example.com site.

```
**:80 is a NameVirtualHost
default server example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)*
```